# highcharts-ng is not displaying pie chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, highcharts

I following example "http://jsfiddle.net/pablojim/cp73s/", but in my app pie chart is not displaying.I am not using jquery.

_______app.js_____

```
var app = angular.module('abc', [
    'highcharts-ng'
]);
 state('app.graph', {
      url: '/graph',
      templateUrl: appHelper.templatePath('app/graph/piechart'),
      controller: 'graphCtrl'
    }).
```

______controller____

```
angular.module('abc').controller('graphCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.highchartsNG = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [20, 20, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
  }
});
```

____index.html____

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/standalone-framework.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.min.js"></script>
```

_____pie.html_____

```
[....
  <highchart id="chart1" config="highchartsNG"></highchart>
....][1]
```

Comment: Is there any error in console ?

Comment: No. it display blank page with chart title

Comment: Your options (like `series` or `title`) should be placed in `options`. Right now your chart is rendering properly, but you simply don't set **any** options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Think you are missing one more file. 
Just include  `"highstock.js"` above `highcharts-ng.js`

Hope this will solve your problem..

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

angular.module('myapp').controller('graphCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.highchartsNG = {
    options: {
      chart: {
        type: 'column'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [20, 20, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
      text: 'Hello'
    },
    loading: false
  }
});
```

Created fiddle for you...
http://jsfiddle.net/anilram25/nfg8kqkn/1/